# Formula Bar to tiny google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, formatting, formula, syntax-highlighting

Can I make it bigger the formula bar in google sheets? I would like to see the entire formula so as a workaround I'm unsing an online IDE to edit.

[image]

Online IDE
https://www.codechef.com/ide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, the size of the formula bar can be only up to 20 rows (either by dragging the bottom of fx bar or by clicking into fx bar and pressing/holding **<kbd>CTRL + DOWN ARROW</kbd>**